# Howto set the TLS Application Data Protocol in OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, encryption, openssl

I have added TLS encryption to one of my C++ applications using OpenSSL.

When I look at the traffic in Wireshark, I notice that you can see what kind of data is being encrypted in the "TLSv1 Record Layer: Application Data Protocol".

I don't really want to reveal this kind of information. Is there a way to set the protocol to "unspecified" or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Application Data Protocol" field displayed in Wireshark is a guess based on the TCP source and destination ports, and is not carried in the TLS stream.

You can check the source code of Wireshark for yourself, it is in dissect_ssl3_record(), epan/dissectors/packet-ssl.c around line 1686.